# Histograms Of Data Along Each Axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose I have two sets of scatter data, which I am plotting on x and y axes:

```
plt.scatter(x,y,s=2)
```

[image: Data plotted on x and y axes]

and each of these datasets has a histogram:

```
hist_x, bins_x, st_x = plt.hist(x)
hist_y, bins_y, st_y = plt.hist(y)
```

[image: Histogram of data along x axis]
[image: Histogram of data along y axis]

What I'm trying to do is display these histograms along each axis of the scatter plot, i.e. to show the distributions that the data has along each axis, in a single image.

How would one go about this?

Comment: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you're looking to use mpl for visualizations. If that's the case, I would suggest looking into the [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) class. You should be able to introduce a 2-2 grid and then fill those plots with the graph and the two distributions with appropriate rotation.

If, however, you're willing to try another package, I would suggest using seaborn. Here's an article on [Visualizing Distributions using Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html) from pydata that describes a method that does exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

I hope these point you in the right direction!

Comment: Thanks, looking into Seaborn now!